tflite model load failed on Android (IsPowerOfTwo(RFFT2D fft_length_data[1]) was not true.)
to get mfcc features from android. built mfcc model with tf.
and I checked works fine.
but when I convert it to tflite and try to load it on Android, error comes while loading.
error logs.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: tensorflow/lite/kernels/rfft2d.cc:117 IsPowerOfTwo(fft_length_data[1]) was not true.
Node number 16 (RFFT2D) failed to prepare.
Failed to apply the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.
at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.allocateTensors(Native Method)
at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.init(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:134)
at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:58)
at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.(NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.java:32)
at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.(Interpreter.java:202)
and full code :
def compute_mfcc(chunk1, chunk2, chunk3, sample_rate=16000, num_mfcc=20):
    padded_chunk = tf.concat([chunk1[-len(chunk1)//2:], chunk2, chunk3[:len(chunk3)//2]], axis=-1)
    
    padded_chunk_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(padded_chunk, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    stft = tf.signal.stft(padded_chunk_tensor, frame_length=128, frame_step=64)
    
    magnitude_spectrograms = tf.abs(stft)
    
    num_spectrogram_bins = magnitude_spectrograms.shape[-1]
    lower_edge_hertz, upper_edge_hertz, num_mel_bins = 80.0, 7600.0, 40
    
    linear_to_mel_weight_matrix = tf.signal.linear_to_mel_weight_matrix(
        num_mel_bins, num_spectrogram_bins, sample_rate, lower_edge_hertz, upper_edge_hertz)
    
    mel_spectrograms = tf.tensordot(magnitude_spectrograms, linear_to_mel_weight_matrix, 1)
    mel_spectrograms.set_shape(magnitude_spectrograms.shape[:-1].concatenate(linear_to_mel_weight_matrix.shape[-1:]))
    
    log_mel_spectrograms = tf.math.log(mel_spectrograms + 1e-9)
    
    mfccs = tf.signal.mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms(log_mel_spectrograms)[..., :num_mfcc]
    
    mfccs_mean = tf.reduce_mean(mfccs, axis=0)
    mfccs_std = tf.math.reduce_std(mfccs, axis=0)
    
    normalized_mfccs = (mfccs - mfccs_mean) / (mfccs_std + 1e-9)
    
    return normalized_mfccs[1]

model convert.
(I also tried optimization)

class MFCCModel(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MFCCModel, self).__init__()
    
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[3, 320], dtype=tf.float32)])
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        chunk1, chunk2, chunk3 = tf.unstack(inputs)
        mfccs = compute_mfcc(chunk1, chunk2, chunk3)
        return mfccs

# Create the model
model = MFCCModel()


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([model.__call__.get_concrete_function()])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, 
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS 
]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True  
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('mfcc_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)


ConcreteFunction Input Parameters:
  inputs (POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD): TensorSpec(shape=(3, 320), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)
Output Type:
  TensorSpec(shape=(20,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)
Captures:
  None

RFFT2D node seems fine with power of two as 128...

please check this error and give any hints to solve it..
thanks
changed fft_lenth other values 256, 256 * 2,,,
every try give same errors..
changed tflite libs to the latest
